# Functionality like alert box

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to get functionality like alert box for example you guys used alert boxes. SO we can not do anything even not able to  switch between tabs in browser without click on "ok" button.  so how could i do with the same thing with my created div and button?

Comment: That's not possible. Browsers decide how to handle this.

Comment: This is not possible. But from UX perspective unlikely you *really* need it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

No. The fact they don't lock up the entire browser is one reason that people use in-page dialogs constructed with mark up in the first place.

Comment: just to note that there is a tag "google-chrome-extension" on the question . it may not be possible from javascript, but it is possible if user installs a "google-chrome-extension"

Answer (score 0):

You can't make a browser-modal dialog this way.

At most using extension API can allow you to switch back to the tab if the user tries to change active tab, but nothing prevents the user from simply closing the page.

Comment: To add to this, see the new <dialog> element which also has a polyfill in github for browsers that dont yet support it. However its modal to the page, not the browser so you could still switch or close tabs.

Comment: @ZigMandel Exactly my point. Page-modal is of course possible, but browser-modal is not and a method of doing so was even [specifically purged](http://blog.chromium.org/2014/07/disabling-showmodaldialog.html).

Comment: Yes. Just wanted to add the <dialog> info which frees us from all sort of pretend-modal hacks to make it modal to the page. i agree with your answer just giving an alternative that partially covers the use case

Comment: "nothing prevents the user from simply closing the page" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload